# Incrementing animation speed in jQuery

Tags: jquery, animation, parameters, performance

I have a bunch of divs inside a containing div. They're all floated left, and only three are visible, with the container's overflow set to hidden. I want to enable the user to hover either the left or right side of the containing div and have the inner divs (slide) animate left or right, the speed of animation growing as the user's mouse nears either side. In the middle, no movement, at the sides, fast movement.

Now, I can adjust speed, and see it reflected if I hover on and off the containing div, but I can't figure out how to change the speed "during" animation. I'm not talking about easing, because I want the user to be able to bring the mouse back to centre and bring the animation to a gentle stop at that point if they choose.

Here's how I'm getting/setting speed param:

`var mouseX = e.pageX-$(this).offset().left,`

```
            width = $(this).innerWidth(),

            speed = Math.round((width-mouseX)*10);
```

I then set animation thusly:

`$("#sliderCont").animate({"left":-1600},speed);`

I use the variable "speed" as the speed param for the animation in the hopes that it will be automatically updated, since I'm using the mouseover event handler, which fires very rapidly, and so I thought the speed amount would change rapidly, too. But apparently not.

Any help please. :)

P.S: this editor is showing a line of code twice, the "var mouseX"... :S It's not part of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try the mousemove event.

Comment: Whoops!! Typo, I actually am using the mousemove event. :P Still isn't working. I can change the animation speed now, but it's jerky as one function ends and another begins. :(